# simplexml_load_file() Error for Unknown Reason

Tags: php, xml, file, ftp, load

I'm running this code...

```
<?php
    $ftp_server = "ftp.nhc.noaa.gov";
    $ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
    $login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, "anonymous", "email@gmail.com");

    $file_list = ftp_nlist($ftp_conn, "/atcf/adv/");

    date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
    $qualifyingtime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-8 hour'));

    unset($file_list[0]);

    foreach ($file_list as $key => $file) {
        $xmlfile = simplexml_load_file("ftp.nhc.noaa.gov" . $file);
        if ($xmlfile->timeEpochSeconds < $qualifyingtime) {
            unset($file_list[$key]);
        } else {
            file_put_contents("http://www.some-website.com/hurricane/active" . $file, $xmlfile);
        }
    }

    var_dump($file_list);
    ftp_close($ftp_conn);
?>
```

...but I'm getting this error and don't know why:

> Warning: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "ftp.nhc.noaa.gov/atcf/adv/ep032017_info.xml" in /home/prww/public_html/hurricane/test.php on line 42

The error is coming from this line of code, according to the error message:

```
$xmlfile = simplexml_load_file("ftp.nhc.noaa.gov" . $file);
```

I have checked, and these files exist, so I don't understand why this error keeps getting thrown. Can anyone tell me why this error is thrown and/or how I can fix it?

Comment: Probably need a scheme `ftp://ftp.nhc.noaa.gov` or `http://ftp.nhc.noaa.gov`.

Comment: `simplexml_load_file()` will look on the local file system, not on the remote FTP server. You will either have to copy the files to your local system and then open them with SimpleXML, or try what @AbraCadaver said.

Comment: And when you get to it, you'll probably need to a local path to write the file:  `file_put_contents("active" . $file, $xmlfile);`